# I'm not sure how to access variables in different child classes

Tags: c++

I am working on a programming assignment where we are learning polymorphism.  We are making a simple fighting game using parent and child classes.

The basic structure is this:

```
class Parent
{
protected:
    int life;
};

class Ninja : public Parent
{
private:
     Ninja (int x);
     void ninjaAttack ();
};

Ninja::Ninja (int x) : Parent ()
{
life = x;
}

Class Monster : public Parent
{
private:
     Monster ();
     void monsterLife ();
};

Monster::Monster() : Parent()
{
}

void Ninja::ninjaAttack ()
{
     life = (life-1);
}

void Monster::monsterAttack()
{
cout << life << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Ninja n1 (4);
    Monster m2;

    Parent * p1 = &n1;
    Parent * p2 = &m1;

    p1 -> ninjaAttack();
    p2 -> monsterAttack();

    return 0;
}
```

So essentially, by initializing a Ninja, I should be making Parent::life = 4, right?  And then by running ninjaAttack, I bring 'life' down to 3.  And then by calling monsterAttack, I should be outputting 3, yeah?

Except it doesn't work.  It outputs zero, every time.  What am I doing wrong?  If I set a variable from the Parent class equal to something in a Child class, how can I actually change the variable in the Parent class, so this new, changed variable can be accessed in the Child classes?

thanks!!

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Your code does not compile for various unrelated reasons, making it very difficult to find the actual problem.

Comment: I suggest you start by compiling your example, the compiler is your friend and will give you insights into what you are doing wrong. Some hints: ninjaAttack and monsterAttack are not methods of the Parent class, so you can't call them on a pointer to the Parent class.

Now to your question - when you call ninjaAttack, you decrease the life count for the ninja object you called the method on - this will not change the life value of a different object

Comment: thanks for the comments, I will make it compile

Answer (score 0):

`Monster` and `Ninja` are two different classes. The shown code initializes two different objects. These two objects are completely independent of each other. The `Ninja` class's constructor, and its `ninjaAttack()` method initializes and modifies the `life` of one of the objects.

The `monsterAttack()` method is invoked on the second object in order to print it's `life` member, but that object has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the `Ninja` object whose `life` was decremented to 3. `Monster`'s `life` was never initialized, and printing its value results in undefined behavior. The output of 0 is one such possible outcome of this undefined behavior.

Comment: thank you.  So if I wanted to use a variable that was accessible to both classes, how would I go about doing that?  Like if I wanted one class's attack to decrement another's life?

Comment: Depending on the situation, either pointers or static class members.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  I'm still having trouble.  I tried it this way:   I made a pointer (*DM) variable in the parent class.  Then I made an int ("HP") in the parent class.   Then, in a child class, I assigned the pointer to the address of the int  (DM = &HP).                 Then, still in the child class, I used the indirection operator to assign a value to HP via DM   (*DM = 123456).        Problem is, when I call HP from another child class, it still shows up as zero.   I'm so confused!  thanks!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with parent or child classes. You have two different objects. One has nothing to do with the other. You have an apple and an orange. You can create as many pointers as you want from the apple's core to it's skin. It's not going to change what's inside the orange.

Answer (score -1):

Some remarks:

- you declare `monsterLife` but you define `monsterAttack`
- Two constructors `Ninja` and `Monster` are private, so you can't call it directly

Come back to your problem, I think you can use `static` variable. For example,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
protected:
    static int life;
};

int Parent::life = 0;

class Ninja : public Parent
{
public:
     Ninja (int x);
     void ninjaAttack ();
};

Ninja::Ninja (int x) : Parent ()
{
    Parent::life = x;
}

class Monster : public Parent
{
public:
     Monster ();
     void monsterLife ();
};

Monster::Monster() : Parent()
{
}

void Ninja::ninjaAttack ()
{
    Parent::life = Parent::life-1;
}

void Monster::monsterLife()
{
    cout << Parent::life << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Ninja n1 (4);
    Monster m2;

    n1.ninjaAttack();
    m2.monsterLife();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All instances here share `life` variable